# Class is abstract; cannot be instantiated error on chisel

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, abstract-class, instantiation, chisel

I have just started using chisel3 and I want to reverse the numbers. This is the **code for the Test bench:**

```
class LengthTest(c: Length) extends PeekPokeTester(c) {
  poke(c.io.x, 12)
  expect(c.io.z, 21)
}



abstract class LengthTester extends ChiselFlatSpec {
  behavior of "Length" 
  backends foreach { backend =>
    it should s"demonstrate usage of functions that generate code in $backend" in {
      Driver(() => new Length, backend)((c) => new LengthTest(c)) should  be (true)
    }
  }
}
```

**And this is the main code**

```
abstract class Length extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val x   = Input(UInt(16.W))
    val z   = Output(UInt(16.W))
  })
  def Reverse(a: UInt) : UInt 
  io.z := Reverse(io.x)
}
```

This throws an error saying class cannot be instantiated. Please help!!

Comment: Why do you think that it should have been possible to instantiate an `abstract` class? What help do you even want in this ? Just remove those `abstract` modifiers.

Comment: Dear Sir, if you remove the abstract modifiers, it throws an error which says 'class Length needs to be abstract, since method Reverse is not defined'. Also, you lose nothing if you are a little nicer.

Comment: If you are new Scala as well (as most new Chisel users are), might I suggest https://github.com/ucb-bar/generator-bootcamp? It provides an introduction to both Chisel and Scala.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the `abstract` keyword from you and delete the `def Reverse(a: UInt) : UInt)` or provide some implementation for it

It seems that [Reverse is an object defined in the chisel utils](https://chisel.eecs.berkeley.edu/api/latest/chisel3/util/Reverse$.html) - so you just need to import it and then you can just io.z := Reverse(io.x)